# Google Play Developer Console Showing Security Alerts Even Updating the Cordova Version 5.0.0

Tags: android, apache, cordova, platform

I have already upgraded my Cordova version to: 5.0.0 and Google Play Developer console still showing this below alert and that affected my latest APK version.

***Your app is using a version of Apache Cordova containing one or more security vulnerabilities. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the app.
Affects APK version 1.***

Comment: Issue is solved now. I have updated both cordova and android platform to latest one. Updated new version 15 days back and still not received any alert from developer center. Installed version are cordova 6.3.0 and Android 5.2.1